# Difficulty in finding structure of "So ... that " or "... that..." as relative pronoun

Tags: prepositions, so

I have a sentence:

> So admired were these pieces that they encouraged the development of earthenware made in imitation of porcelain and instigated research into the method of their manufacture.

I can't find structure of it. Does "So" in here mean 'too/so much/many'? or is it part of 'so..that'?

What is the structure of "admired were these pieces"? Adj+verb+noun!?

Comment: It looks to me like a kind of [fronting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/fronting) (moving a syntactic element from its "natural" position to the front of an utterance). The natural phrasing would be *These pieces **were so admired** that they blah blah* (or ***...were admired so much...***). It's a poetic/literary device, not common in normal conversational contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an type of inversion. Moving that syntactic element to the front of a sentence has an effect of emphasis. The writer wants to emphasize "so admired" in this case.

Another example:

> *So angry was he that he couldn’t speak*.

The normal order is:

> *He was so angry that he couldn’t speak*.

Comment: In the formal writing, Is it common?
which is more preferable? adj+so that or so+adj+that

Comment: I think it's like what @FumbleFingers said: "*It's a poetic/literary device, not common in normal conversational contexts*."

Answer (score 2):

> *So admired were these pieces that they encouraged the development of*
>   *earthenware made in imitation of porcelain and instigated research*
>   *into the method of their manufacture*.

"So" is a degree adverb (not unlike "very") modifying "admired".

The phrase "so admired" has been preposed (fronted), no doubt to serve as a link to the preceding discourse.  Preposing expressions with *so* + noun/adjective  is fairly uncommon and found mainly in formal discourse/textbooks/literary works etc.

Preposing certain elements like this triggers subject-auxiliary inversion: the basic order would be *These pieces were so admired that they encouraged ... .*

Note also that the complement clause *that they encouraged the development of earthenware ... .*  is licensed (specifically permitted) by the *so* that modifies *admired*. Complements like this are called 'indirect complements' because although they follow the head word, it is not the head word that licenses them.